# How to fix game compatibility issue with FIFA 2001 on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, compatibility

I used to play EA Sports FIFA 2001 when I had Windows 2000 and Windows XP.

Now I installed it on Windows 7 and keep the CD in the laptop.
But I got this error message *"Please insert the correct CD-Rom, select OK and restart the application".*

I don't know what causes this. But without fixing it I could not play the game.

Comment: I am not sure if it is compatibility issue. I just guessed that.

Comment: Have you reviewed EA sports link? https://help.ea.com/article/cd-rom-troubleshooting. And just to be sure, this is the orriginal game disk? not a back up or some other copy?

Comment: I have the original disk but I forgot the password so I can not use it. I got this backup disk and it gives me this error. I am going to read the link you gave me. Thanks

Comment: I just tried the original disk. It gives me the same error. Read Me section said about the graphic card in your computer should be compatible with Direct X. I checked that it is compatible with DirectX 11 that came with windows 7.

Answer (score 0):

Try enabling compatibility mode. (Right click the .exe, go to properties, and then the compatibility tab. Check the appropriate checkbox and select Windows XP as the mode to run it in.

Answer (score 0):

Fifa of that age has early copy protection and only runs on XP - You could try an XP vm with virtualbox mapping the cd drive direct to the VM, or just install XP.